# Amazon S3 currency charges

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-s3

I am looking into using Amazon S3 and I live in the UK and have a UK credit card.

It seems that Amazon bills in $s, my bank will change me for the exchange from £ to $ and this means it will likely cost me more in those charges than actually using S3.

Is there a way to pay in £?

Comment: Your UK Bank will only charge a transaction fee in fact some banks don't, this fee is normally around £1.00, when making USD payments online you are effectively not converting currency because its a wire transfer and exchange rate is only the thing that will vary, its not the same as converting GBP to USD ready for your thomas cook holiday. You should ask your bank the cost and factor that into your margins since I believe amazon is USD only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot find any documented page on AWS documentation to confirm this, from personal experience I can verify that unfortunately it is not currently possible to pay Amazon Web Services in GBP (£), or any currency other than USD ($) for that matter.

I'm also a UK-based AWS customer and can confirm that in addition to the exchange rate, the UK banks (e.g. [Barclays](http://www.barclays.co.uk/cs/Satellite?c=Info_C&pagename=BarclaysOnline/BOPopUp&cid=1242601730380), [HSBC](https://investments.hsbc.co.uk/non-sterling-transactions)) also charge a transaction fee for all non-GBP transactions, typically 2.75% on debit card transactions and 2.99% on credit card transactions. To give an example, recent bank statement entries of mine show:

```
Date         Description                                           Paid Out (£)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
03 Nov 2014  NON-STERLING TRANSACTION FEE                          0.04
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
03 Nov 2014  Amazon Web Services aws.amazon.co WA                  1.37
             02.19 USD @ 1.5985
             Visa Exchange Rate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So while it is not possible to pay in GBP I have found the non-sterling transaction fees to be low enough that it has not been an issue (mine above on credit card at 2.99%).

Until around November 2013 they used to just bundle their fee into the exchange rate so you couldn't tell how much the bank were charging and the true details of the currency exchange but the Financial Conduct Authority changed has forced the banks to be more transparent (see [Conduct of Business Requirements Q7-9](http://www.fca.org.uk/firms/firm-types/payment-services-institutions/psr-faqs?category=conduct-of-business-requirements-or-cob-requirements) for details).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. May I ask which bank you are with?

Comment: The example statement entries above are from an HSBC corporate VISA statement. Other banks are available :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Billing FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/billing/faqs/), it is now possible to choose a non-USD currency for your AWS account:

> **Q: Which currencies can I choose from?**
>
> AUD – Australian Dollar
>
> CHF – Swiss Franc
>
> DKK – Danish Krone
>
> EUR – Euro
>
> GBP – British Pound
>
> HKD – Hong Kong Dollar
>
> JPY – Japanese Yen
>
> NOK – Norwegian Krone
>
> NZD – New Zealand Dollar
>
> SEK – Swedish Krona
>
> USD – United States Dollar
>
> ZAR – South African Rand

Comment: To assist anyone that may come across this in the future, currently (Jul 2016) you can change this on the "Payment Methods" screen by clicking the link next to the "Make Payment" button.